# How to read each Json object in my input file to a row in spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and Scala and I am trying to learn spark for one of my learning project. I have a JSON file which look like this:

```
[
  {
"year": 2012,
"month": 8,
"title": "Batman"
},
  {
"year": 2012,
"month": 8,
"title": "Hero"
 },
 {
"year": 2012,
"month": 7,
"title": "Robot"
 }
]
```

I started reading this json to spark DataFrame file so i tried following:

```
spark.read
  .option("multiline", true)
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .json(filePath)
```

It reads the JSON but convert the data to spark columns. My requirement is to read each data object as one individual column.

I want to read it to a spark DataFrame where I expect output like following:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|json                                    |
+----------------------------------------+
|{"year":2012,"month":8,"title":"Batman"}|
|{"year":2012,"month":8,"title":"Hero"}  |
|{"year":2012,"month":7,"title":"Robot"} |
|{"year":2011,"month":7,"title":"Git"}   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `toJSON`

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("multiline", true)
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .json(filePath).toJSON
```

Now

```
df.show(false)

+----------------------------------------+
|value                                   |
+----------------------------------------+
|{"month":8,"title":"Batman","year":2012}|
|{"month":8,"title":"Hero","year":2012}  |
|{"month":7,"title":"Robot","year":2012} |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My purpose is not to print it but read in such a way that each JSON object becomes a row. I guess reading first and then converting to JSON will have unnecessary cost. is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Kishore's Answer gives you each Json Object in a separate row.

Or when say each object in a separate row dd you mean below output?

|month| title|year|

|    8|Batman|2012|

Comment: I want the way Kishore has mentioned but if you look at the code it is first reading  (.json) and converting it to JSON (.toJSON) which I think is a costly way of doing it. So I want to know if this is the most efficient way or not.